# Read PDF irregular table using python

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to extract information from a PDF. However, I'm having trouble with the table structure.

As of now, the best way I was able to extract the info was using a pytesseract.

Here's a copy of the pdf:

[image]

I don't know if such an option exist but I was thinking a using bouding box to parse every box in the table independently.

If anyone has a suggestion or an other way of doing it that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Check out `camelot`

Comment: @KJ that is what I had in mind but is there a way to differenciate between those zones of interest

Comment: Is it a scanned PDF?